# Why DC spurs are present in FFT plot of ADC

Tags: adc

While reading about coherent and non-coherent sampling of ADCs in general, I read that we need to *neglect first 6 DC bins in the output FFT plot while calculating parameters like SNR, SFDR etc.* for the ADC. I had thought that DC bins correspond to the spurs introduced by the power supply source. Is there any reason why 6 bins in particular is being omitted?

Comment: Context missing... sounds like a "rule of thumb" thing, allowing for (a) smearing due to windowing, and possibly (b) elimination of 50/60Hz interfering signals. But without context, this is a guess. Perhaps link to the source of this quote...

Comment: I found it in Page 7 of this [link](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/eval_boards/ADC_ANALYZER_0.pdf). The default value for DC leakage is considered as 6. How do we arrive at this value?

Comment: That page says "The number of bins (at dc) that are not used in calculating SNR and SINAD. Typically, this can be left at the default value of 6."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare discussion of "Fundamental leakage(bins)" and "DC leakage(bins)" on p.7, and realise you can model DC as a fundamental at 0Hz. Therefore the ignored bins would typically be approx. half the "Fundamental" bins.

It does depend on the windowing function (see p.21) selected; in FFT plots you should be able to see spectral lines broaden with the Blackman window, both from the fundamental and from any DC component.

But the acid test is: if you decrease the number of ignored bins, does the S/N measurement degrade? If so, you are measuring spectral leakage from the DC component, not actual noise.